# Jquery function loading content and removing doesn't repeat it

Tags: jquery, animation, onclick, transition

On `clickPrev();` function I'm removing the class animate and I go back to previous page.

I need to follow all my function untill the click `.prev` then, I load again the "('../views/product-page.html" the class .anamate hasn't been removed properly as the function keep triggering the class .animate

Do I need to prevent the callback?

```
    $('.show-content').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#load-content').load('../views/product-page.html ' + href);

    $('.container').addClass('loaded', function() {
        $('#load-content').html('<img id="loader" src="../assets/images/bx_loader.gif">');
        $('#loader').css({ border:'none', position:'absolute', top:'24px', left:'48px', boxShadow:'none' });
    });


    // Now add Class Animate once the CSS3 transition is ended
    $("#load-content").bind("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function(){
        $(this).addClass('animate');
        clickPrev();
    });

    });

//now GO BACK to previews page and repeat the transition and remove the classes.
    clickPrev = function () {
        $('#load-content .prev').on('click', function (){

        $('.animate').removeClass('animate');

        $("#load-content").bind("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function(){
        $('.loaded').removeClass('loaded');
        $('#show-content').remove();
        $('.animate').removeClass('animate');
    });

       });
     }
```

Comment: please provide your html too

Comment: @Anoop Joshi http://jsfiddle.net/79BPM/  it's not the complete one but its almost like that

Comment: @AnoopJoshi the function clickPrev fires again when I try to reload the $('#load-content').html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this code. Let me know whether it worked or not..

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.show-content').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var href = $(this).attr('href');
            $('#load-content').load('../views/product-page.html ' + href);

            $('.container').addClass('loaded');


            // Now add Class Animate once the CSS3 transition is ended
            $("#load-content").bind("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function () {
                $(this).addClass('animate');
                $('#load-content .prev').trigger("click");
            });

        });
        //now GO BACK to previews page and repeat the transition and remove the classes.
        $('#load-content .prev').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('.animate').removeClass('animate');

            $("#load-content").bind("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function () {
                $('.loaded').removeClass('loaded');
                $('#show-content').remove();
                $('.animate').removeClass('animate');
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: thanks but the .trigger("click"); doens't work. that's why I created the function clickPrev(); any other ideas?

Comment: would you be able to help me please?

Comment: Otherwise can I use $.when? do you know how? the callback should be removed somehow

Comment: can you explain what is your needed functionality step by step.. Then i can definetely help you. You can edit the question with your actual needs. what is the expected functionality if click on prev.. like that.

Comment: Sure! doesn't work this fiddle. I need to follow all my function untill I click .prev then, I load again the  "('../views/product-page.html" the class .anamate hasn't been removed properly as the function keep triggering the class .animate

Comment: everything else is working fine? only the prev click is not working right?

Comment: yes, all good, untill after the .prev has worked If I repeat it won't work

Comment: $('.show-content').on('click') doesn't load the second time. as the function clickPrev() keeps running

Comment: in prev click you want to remove the class animate?

Comment: in the fiddler i'm not getting any repeated prev() click calls

Comment: on my function the .prev doen't get trigger , that's why I've done the function